# Typescript union type is raising an error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The object that I have defined:

```
export const exceptionMsg: ErrorMessages = {
    badRequest: 'bla bla bla',
    user: {
       notFound: 'The user bla bla bla',
    },
};
```

The interface **ErrorMessages** that I have defined for it:

```
interface ErrorMessages {
    [x: string]: string | { [x: string]: string };
}
```

Basically the properties of my object can either be a string or an object whose values are also strings. That is what I am defining. However, when using this object in another file, this error is being raised:

> Property 'notFound' does not exist on type 'string | { [x: string]: string; }'.
>     Property 'notFound' does not exist on type 'string'.

The code where I use it is just this:

```
throw new BadRequestException(exceptionMsg.pipeline.notFound);
```

I am relatively new to Typescript but after reading the documentation I cannot seem to find what I am missing.

Comment: you mean when you use `exceptionMsg.notFound` that error is rasied?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, let me edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you declare `exceptionMsg` as `ErrorMessages` any information from the initializer such as the properties `user` and `badRequest` is lost, only the declared type `ErrorMessages` is known about `exceptionMsg`.

So when you access `exceptionMsg.user`, ts, based on the signature in `ErrorMessages`  only knows that `exceptionMsg.user` is of type `string | { [x: string]: string }`. When you have a property of a union type, since that property can be either of those types, it is only safe to access properties common to both types, so when you drill down again, you get an error as `string` does not have an index signature or the `notFound` property.

You can use a type guard to narrow the type:

```
if (typeof exceptionMsg.user !== "string") {
  exceptionMsg.user.notFound
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71A4YYEsUCyqA5gFxwCiUU0BwqqAhsfXALxwDeAUHH3ACNGAEwBKwAI4BXejHIByAQBtGglWsbyANL35TUwKOR79TyCDABiEKcmEKAKgAtgcfYY2flmnaYC+On4A3NzcuMgwhgBmjFiU1LT0TCyoXLp8ANog5OhQ4cQAujkwecjEcAA+XHBZxaWFdflwwdx+obhRcAAUMACeYMAQnZjYeIQkAHTuUHAAhGwcAES5+YsAlGl8Izj4yETEUwZQE+ZWNnatQA)

What you really want probably, is to remove `ErrorMessages` from the type of the constant and le inference do it's job. If you want to constrain the constant to extends `ErrorMessages` you can use a generic function:

```
function createErrorMessages<T extends ErrorMessages>(o: T): T{
  return o;
}
export const exceptionMsg = createErrorMessages({
    badRequest: 'bla bla bla',
    user: {
       notFound: 'The user bla bla bla',
    },
});

exceptionMsg.user.notFound // ok now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKJSgeygWQgZ3zgHMDkBvAKGRuQG0APALmXzClGIF0W2ORiyAD4V6zVu048J-QQF8A3JTmVKMAK4gEYYJhDIEUCHEjosuAkVL4APABVkEBpBAATfGgzY8hEgQB8ABSYLHYAlKFUNEZg6lD6mEoqTgAO2GAGemyODEgpOno4+IIAvAZGJhBm3pZ++IFRtABGcK4AShAAjuoEYCwA5E0ANnDIw6Pj-QA01LTq+NAsjbQ0IJhgAGKYmq4DdgAWKPPQYyOnEyPTszRyM3JhSpROeQUgRcQAdMdQH2ub225kAB6IHITAAa2QIBSAHdkEA)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. However, I am still trying to fully understand what is the createErrorMessages function doing. It just returns whatever it takes as a param as an object of type ErrorMessages, but I do not understand why this does not raise an error but my solution does.